# How do I use onWindowFocusChanged(...) properly? Code seem ok... (included of course!)

Tags: java, android, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

Following is my code (from MainActivity.java):

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean isFocused)
{

    super.onWindowFocusChanged(isFocused);
    long tempTime = 0;
    if(!isFocused)
    {
        try
        {
            FileOutputStream  fos = this.openFileOutput("timekeeper", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream  oos = new ObjectOutputStream (fos);
            oos.writeObject(AnimationUtils.currentAnimationTimeMillis());
            oos.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            //Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            FileInputStream  fis = this.openFileInput("timekeeper");
            ObjectInputStream  ois = new ObjectInputStream (fis);
            tempTime = ois.readLong();
            ois.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            //Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if((tempTime != 0))
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I checked the code, and it always posts the Toats (when not //'d :)).
What is missing?
Is this the correct way to store/recall information in an android activity?
I did not declare the file anywhere else than in the above code. Should I have?

Let me know if I left out important information...

Thanks!